# Jquery Datatable ASP.NET Gridview Large DataSet

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am using "DataTables Jquery" with an ASP.NET Gridview...

The gridview works perfectly fine for small datasets but for Large Datasets (>5000 rows) it takes some time to load and while the grid is loading the Loading Circle also Does not appear..

**ASP.NET PseudoCode -**

```
<body id="dt_example">
<form runat=server>
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5">
    <RowStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:GridView>
        </form>
</body>
```

**JavaScript -**

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#gv').dataTable({
                    'bJQueryUI': true,
                    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
                    'bAutoWidth': true
            });
        });
        </script>
```

**Code Behind -**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QueryRslt(passType, val);
        gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }


    public void QueryRslt(string Type, string Value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
        {
            if (Type == "TaskStatus")
            {
                gv.DataSource = tsk
                               .Where(x => x.Status == Value)
                                        .Select(m => new
                                        {
                                            ID = m.Incident_ID,
                                            TaskID = m.Task_ID,
                                            CI = m.CI,
                                            Status = m.Status,
                                            Priority = m.Priority,
                                            ReportedDate = m.Task_Assign_Time,
                                            AssigneeGroup = m.Assignee_Group,
                                            AssignedGroup = m.Assigned_Group,
                                            RespondDate = m.Incident_Responded_Date,
                                            Reason = m.Status_Reason
                                        }).ToList();
                gv.DataBind();
            }
            else if (Type == "IncidentStatus")
            {
                gv.DataSource = inc
                               .Where(x => x.Status == Value)
                                        .Select(m => new
                                        {
                                            ID = m.Incident_ID,
                                            CI = m.CI,
                                            Status = m.Status,
                                            Priority = m.Priority,
                                            ReportedDate = m.Incident_Reported_Date,
                                            AssigneeGroup = m.Assignee,
                                            AssignedGroup = m.Assigned_Group,
                                            RespondDate = m.Incident_Responded_Date,
                                            Reason = m.Status_Reason
                                        }).ToList();
                gv.DataBind();
            }}}
```

The loading Gif appear for a fraction of second and then disappears...

So there are 2 things i want to know -

1. Display Loading gif until the whole gridview is populated..
2. Decrease the time of processing the data..

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP.NET generic handlers instead of ASP.NET GridView binding in code-behind.

like

```
$('#gv').dataTable({
                'bJQueryUI': true,
                'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
                'bAutoWidth': true,
                 'bProcessing': true,
                 'bServerSide': true,
                 'sAjaxSource': '/handlers/handlerName.ashx'
        });
```

and the handler contains

```
   public class handlerName : IHttpHandler
    {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // THOSE PARAMETERS ARE SENT BY THE PLUGIN
                var iDisplayLength = int.Parse(context.Request["iDisplayLength"]);

                ////HOLD DISPLAY START
                var iDisplayStart = int.Parse(context.Request["iDisplayStart"]);

                ////HOLD SORT COLUMN
                var iSortCol = int.Parse(context.Request["iSortCol_0"]);

                ////HOLD SORT DIRECTION SUCH AS ASC AND DESC
                var iSortDir = context.Request["sSortDir_0"];

                ////HOLD SEARCH KEYWORD
                var sSearch = context.Request["sSearch"];             


                var variableToHoldData = className.functionName();

                // DEFINE AN ORDER FUNCTION BASED ON THE ISORTCOL PARAMETER
                Func<variableToHoldData, object> order = p =>
                {
                    //IF SORT COLUMN IS 1, fieldName
                   if (iSortCol == 1)
                   {
                        return p.fieldName2;
                   }
                //    //IF SORT COLUMN IS 2, SORT BY fieldName
                   else if (iSortCol == 2)
                   {
                        return p.fieldName3;
                    }

                    }
                    //SORT BY fieldName
                   return p.fieldName1;
                };
                // DEFINE THE ORDER DIRECTION BASED ON THE ISORTDIR PARAMETER
                variableToHoldData = "desc" == iSortDir ? variableToHoldData.OrderByDescending(order) : variableToHoldData.OrderBy(order);


                // PREPARE AN ANONYMOUS OBJECT FOR JSON SERIALIZATION
                var result = new
                {
                    iTotalRecords = variableToHoldData.Count(),
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = variableToHoldData.Count(),
                    aaData = variableToHoldData

                        //SEARCH BY FIELD NAME
                        .Where(p => p.fieldName1.ToLower().Contains(sSearch.ToLower()) || p.fieldName2.ToLower().Contains(sSearch.ToLower()) || p.fieldName3.ToLower().Contains(sSearch.ToLower()) )

                        //SELECT FIELDS
                        .Select(p => new[] { p.fieldName1.ToString(), p.fieldName2.ToString(), p.fieldName3.ToString() })
                        .Skip(iDisplayStart)
                        .Take(iDisplayLength)

                };

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                //CONVERT RESULT INTO JSON
                var json = serializer.Serialize(result);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.Write(json);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
           public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }   



    public class className
    {
        public string fieldName1 { get; set; }
        public string fieldName2 { get; set; }
        public string fieldName3 { get; set; }


        public static IEnumerable<className> functionName()
        {


            //RETURN DATA FROM SOURCE
            DT= obj.ReturnData();

            //CHECK CANDIDATE PROFILE DATATABLE  IS NULL
            if (DT != null && DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
                {
                    yield return new className
                    {



                        fieldName1 = row["columnName1"].ToString(),


                        fieldName1 = row["columnName2"].ToString(),


                        fieldName1 = row["columnName3"].ToString(),                 


                    };
                }
            }

        }

    }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any solution where i don't change the GridView..
I wan to retain the gridView in all circumstances